# Why do bypass settings in Github Actions rulesets not apply?

Tags: github-actions

I am learning Github Actions.

I have a repository with no branch protection rules, but several rulesets targeting the default branch. (It seems to me that doing things via rulesets is the new proper way to protect a branch from certain activities.)

The rules in the rulesets do very common things: require pull requests, block deletions, and require certain status checks to pass. Nothing exotic.

I have added [bypasses for my administrators for each of these rules](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/creating-rulesets-for-a-repository#granting-bypass-permissions-for-your-ruleset).

I have a manually triggered workflow. I am using it to test `git` operations in a Github Actions environment.

In the workflow, I check out the repository. I add a line to a dummy file. I call `git commit -m "Added line"` and `git push`. This fails.

Specifically, when I trigger this workflow manually as a repository administrator on the default branch, the workflow fails and I see:

```
remote: error: GH013: Repository rule violations found for refs/heads/main.        
remote: Review all repository rules at http://github.com/foo/bar/rules?ref=refs%2Fheads%2Fmain        
remote: 
remote: - Required status check "Job: Maven Verify" is expected.        
remote: 
remote: - Changes must be made through a pull request.
```

(Remember, again, I have bypass settings in place for my repository administrator.)

Why are the bypass settings not taking effect? (I can see that the `GITHUB_ACTOR` is indeed a repository administrator, so I would expect that the `git push` operation would be allowed.)

Answer (score 1):

Answering for posterity.

My question was essentially: for `git` operations in a Github Actions workflow, how do I tie a `GITHUB_TOKEN` to an organization role such that the `git` operations can proceed? The answer is: you cannot. If you must operate as a certain identity, such that you are granted particular permissions, you must (as of November 2023 anyway) use a (preferably fine-grained) personal access token that is granted those permissions.

The immediate question that follows is: how do you get `git` to be configured in a safe, non-persistent way such that for certain operations it will operate with the permissions granted to your personal access token?

If you have a workflow that uses `actions/checkout` (very common), be aware that whatever token it uses (`GITHUB_TOKEN` by default) will be persisted to `git` configuration by default. This means `git` operations that occur in any subsequent step in your job will use those permissions by default, even if you try to set the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable with an `env` setting in a given step.

If you want to let `actions/checkout` run with no or limited permissions (very common), then you should take care to ensure it does not persist the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, because whatever token it persists will affect all subsequent steps in your job.

So if `actions/checkout` does not persist the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, then you must take care to ensure that subsequent `git` operations have some way of authenticating.

You have several choices. Some involve rewriting the usually-`https`-based `origin` URL to include your personal access token. Others involve passing the extra HTTP header containing the base-64-encoded version of your personal access token. But with these options you may now be in the business of building a URL out of several environment variables and ensuring that you do URL and/or base 64 encoding properly. I didn't want to be in that business.

Another possibility is to use the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable, which is what I ended up doing. If you set its value to the name of an executable temporary shell script that simply echoes the value of an environment variable, and if you set that environment variable's value to be your personal access token, then your personal access token is not exposed in the log files or artifacts, and `git` itself does the URL building and wrangling for you.

I hope this is helpful to future readers.  Thanks to @Benjamin W. for the time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens), the permissions of that workflow are those of [`GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication). There are two possible defaults: read/write permissions, or read-only permissions; these can be set at repo and organization level.

In any case, even with write permissions, the workflow isn't considered to have admin permissions, despite the GitHub actor being a user that is.

Comment: Thank you very much. So is there a permission I can grant the user in question? Currently the only permission this user has (deliberately) is `contents: 'write'`. And: does this all effectively mean that workflows using `GITHUB_TOKEN` can *never* bypass any rulesets, since one cannot craft any bypass settings involving this user?

Comment: @LairdNelson You can use the personal access token with the required permissions, for example with repo write access, from a user who is allowed to bypass the rules. You have to set it as the value of `GITHUB_TOKEN` in the corresponding step, or most simply in the checkout step (credentials are persisted).

Comment: Thanks again. I had read that using PATs was an anti-pattern. This is all extraordinarily confusing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @LairdNelson The new [fine-grained tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token) address many of the concerns, as you can give very precise permission scopes.

Comment: I have set up a PAT. I have granted it the permissions I need for `git push` to work (write access to Contents). (This looks suspiciously familiar, since the `GITHUB_TOKEN` had these permissions before.) Not surprisingly (to me), everything still fails because there is nothing to say that the actor is in a list of users that can bypass the rulesets. I suppose I need to grant it additional permissions. None of them look applicable. I guess I'll try them one-by-one. How infuriatingly tedious.

Comment: I think I have finally figured out what was happening. My two-step job first uses the `actions/checkout@v4` action. I had not told it to use a special token, so it was using `GITHUB_TOKEN` by default, whose permissions were deliberately `{}`. My second job set `GITHUB_TOKEN` to my PAT, but the `actions/checkout` action cached the prior value of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`. I specified the PAT in the checkout action and nowhere else and everything worked. My guess is I could also somehow tell `actions/checkout` not to cache and then set `GITHUB_TOKEN` only for the push step.

Comment: @LairdNelson That's correct, there's a [boolean setting](https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) `persist-credentials`.

Comment: Turning off `persist-credentials` now leads to a whole host of other problems in the `git push` step. Although I have set the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable to the value of my PAT for the `git push` step, it is of course never persisted to any kind of configuration, so `git` has no idea, now, that it exists. It looks like I'm going to have to do something ugly with `GIT_ASKPASS`. Amazing.

Comment: Why don't you give your PAT the exact permissions you need, use it with actions/checkout, and *do* persist the credentials?

Comment: Because I don't actually need any permissions at all to use `actions/checkout` and I wanted to see if there were a way to use as few permissions as possible at each step along the way.

Comment: You do need `contents: read` at least. Another option could be to use the GitHub API to perform Git operations via API; then you can use `GITHUB_TOKEN` in the environment, and don't have to put something together for the Git client itself, as you describe in the answer.

Comment: Actually, interestingly, `permissions: {}` on the checkout job works great. Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defining-access-for-the-github_token-scopes-1 (search for "disable permissions for all of the available scopes").

Comment: @LairdNelson I'm fairly sure that sets the permissions to the defaults, and not to `none` for everything. If you set *any* permissions, the rest are set to `none`. `contents: none` shouldn't (and doesn't) let you check out anything.